# solr error Error getting leader from zk

Tags: solr, solrcloud

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: There is conflicting information about the leader of shard: shard2 our state says:http://xxxxx:9003/solr/collectionname_shard2_replica1/ but zookeeper says:http://xxxxxx:9006/solr/collectionname_shard2_replica1/
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.getLeader(ZkController.java:1013)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.register(ZkController.java:940)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.register(ZkController.java:883)
at org.apache.solr.core.ZkContainer$2.run(ZkContainer.java:184)
```

above mentioned error is displayed in solr admin console. 9003 is valid instance. I want to remove 9006 from clusterjson and leader file. How??

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into your solr gui under `cloud -> tree`. Make sure that in the folder `/overseer_elect/election` are only your current solr instances.

A simple way to recognize if there are dead solr instances in the `/overseer_elect/election` folder is to shutdown solr and then use the `zkCli.sh` zookeeper script to look into the `/overseer_elect/election` folder. If you still have files in this folder, you have dead solr instances. To solve this issue remove this instances with the `zkCli.sh` script and restart solr.